# Sed copy first string and prepend it to line

Tags: shell, sed, text-processing

I have a file:

```
Text1 text2 50
Text3 text4 60
```

I would like to make the following using sed command:

```
Text1 Text1 text2 50
Text3 Text3 text4 60
```

I need to copy the first string and add it to the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/[^ ]\+ /&&/' input-file
```

Assumes a space as separator, and not a tab.  `&` is shorthand for "entire match" when used on replacement side of `s///` substitution

Note that prior answer `s/.* /&&/` above only works for 2-word inputs. It's too greedy.  So we're matching one or more non-space characters followed by a space.